# Recursively merge similar elements in a list

Tags: java, list, recursion

I would like to group/merge/union rectangles that are close (similar) to each other. There is no particular reason why I tried this recursively but it seemed appropriate.

However I am missing something here. The output is not correct and I did not consider the fact that rectangles that are merged later down the road might be close now to rectangles that I considered "un-mergeable" and put into the `finalList`

The merging and the check closeness method are working properly.

```
public static ArrayList<Rect> mergeCloseRects(ArrayList<Rect> sourceList, ArrayList<Rect> finalList) {

    Rect rect = sourceList.get(0).clone();
    sourceList.remove(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < sourceList.size(); i++) {

        if (rectsAreClose(rect, sourceList.get(i)) {
            // put merged rectangle on top of the list
            sourceList.add(0, getMergeRect(rect, sourceList.get(i)));
            // remove rectangle that was merged with rect
            sourceList.remove(i + 1);
            mergeCloseRects(sourceList, finalList);
        }
    }

    // if rect has no close neighbours
    finalList.add(rect);

    return finalList;
}
```

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

As you can see the rectangles are not really merged. The lower rectangle stayed in the list. The green outline tells where the new rectangle(s) will be.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a better fit for iteration than recursion: you can naturally keep going until there is nothing left to merge. I would think your code should look something like:

```
while(!getListCloseRectangles(sourceList).isEmpty()) {
    List<Rect> rectanglesToMerge = getListCloseRectangles(sourceList);
    sourceList.removeAll(rectanglesToMerge);
    sourceList.add(createMergedRect(rectanglesToMerge));
}
```

This also allows for the situation in which getListCloseRectangles can return more than two rectangles at a time. But it will still work fine if it only ever returns two items in the list.